# Is it required create the document first, before calling pouchdb db.putAttachment function to attach data to the document

Tags: pouchdb

**Issue:**

Calling the pouchdb 'putAttachment' function doesn't write the attachment details to db.

**Background:**

Based on the example provided at the pouchdb site I have written my code to create attachments (http://pouchdb.com/guides/attachments.html).

```
db.putAttachment('mydoc', 'myattachment.png', myBase64String, 'image/png');
```

**Question:**

Is it required to create the 'mydoc' first before I start calling the db.putAttachment function to create attachments ?

If the 'mydoc' document is not yet there then will it be created automatically by pouchdb.

At the moment when I call the code 'db.putAttachment' then nothing happens (no 'mydoc' document is created or attachment created in the db)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, if the document doesn't exist, then PouchDB will create it for you.

Comment: i am using the pouchdb 3.3.1.  Is it something to do with with the version of the pouchdb that I am using. Any clue why isn't the db.putAttachment() working for me.

Comment: Seems there's a bug in the documentation. You need to do `db.putAttachment('mydoc', 'myattachment.png', null, myBase64String, 'image/png');`

Comment: Actually scratch that; it is working. I cannot reproduce your error. Here is a live example showing that it works: http://bl.ocks.org/nolanlawson/50de0368426e02148e99

Comment: I found a mistake in my code. I was appending an additional string value to 'myBase64String' hence the attachment was never created. At the same time pouchDB was not throwing any error. So I thought that the issue was with pouchDB. But infact my code had the bug.